# Pass Value of Y & Update Spline Chart at every second

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to fetch data from my sql server database and pass reader value as Y axis value to spline chart which updates at every one second. Below is the code I have tried but it fetches value only one time and updates spline chart at every one second with the same fetched value. I want it to fetch value from database at every one second and plot. Please help me How can I solve my problem.

```js
        public string runquery()
        {
            /* local variable declaration */
            string result = string.Empty;
           
            string connectionString = "Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - Connection Succeeded!");
                string selectfromtable = "Select  data_col From infobenchtable order by id_col desc";
                SqlCommand selectfromtableequery = new SqlCommand(selectfromtable, connection);
                SqlDataReader rd = selectfromtableequery.ExecuteReader();
                if (rd.Read() == true) { result =  rd.GetString(0); }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
        public ActionResult SplineUpdateEachSecond()
        {
           string stringtopass = string.Empty;
            //string methodresult = runquery();
            stringtopass = @"// set up the updating of the chart each second
                                       var series = this.series[0];
                                       setInterval(function() {
                                          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                             y =" + runquery() + @"; //To Edit for azure
                                          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                       }, 10000);";
            //System.Windows.Forms.Mess
            List<object> points = new List<object>(20);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = -19; i <= 0; i++)
                points.Add(new { X = now.AddSeconds(i), Y = rand.NextDouble() });
            Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
                
                .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = false } })
                .InitChart(new Chart
                           {
                               DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line,
                               MarginRight = 10,
                               Events = new ChartEvents
                                        {
                                            Load = "ChartEventsLoad"
                                        }
                           })
            .AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad",
                                              runquery()) 


                .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Live random data" })
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                          {
                              Type = AxisTypes.DateTime,
                              TickPixelInterval = 150
                          })
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                          {
                              Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Value" },
                              PlotLines = new[]
                                          {
                                              new YAxisPlotLines
                                              {
                                                  Value = 0,
                                                  Width = 1,
                                                  Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080")
                                              }
                                          }
                          })
                .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
                .AddJavascripFunction("TooltipFormatter",
                                      @"return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                       Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                                       Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);")
                .SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = false })
                .SetExporting(new Exporting { Enabled = false })
                .SetSeries(new Series
                           {
                               Name = "Random data",
                               Data = new Data(points.ToArray())
                           });

            return View(chart);
        }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is a new point in the database every second to actually retrieve? If you're grabbing the latest data value from the data base, but there's no new data, you're going to keep getting the same value

Comment: Yes I have New value at every one second.Lets keep aside database I have incremented value in runquery instead of fetching from database but it still throws same value.What I observed is we have written code in charteventload event is that a problem.